# Initializing Variables from an Array of names and values

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables, initialization

I am programming in C and have initialized 2 arrays as shown below:

```
char names[3][10] = {"foo","ba", "foofoo"};
int values[3] = {1,2,3};
```

I would like to initialize these in the form:

```
int foo = 1;
int ba = 2;
int foofoo = 3;
```

This would not be a problem if the arrays were small, but I am wondering if there is a particular way in which I could initialize these variable names within a for-loop?

Comment: Nope, no can do. In c++ you could use a std::map, but even then, you would still only have 1 variable (think of it as an array) whose elements you could index with a string (foo, ba, foofoo) and whose values would contain (1,2,3).

Comment: no there is no way to do it i `C` but you can initialize the array within `for loop`

Comment: You might like to consider writing a function to be called on program start-up setting the arrays' elements as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as C is compiled and not interpreted.